# Better way to remove the json node at deeper level

Tags: java, json

The below is my sample json file which conatins the information about the cars, I wanted to remove the "city" from the below json data at a time.
Since the json data contains too many city nodes at very depath, I don't want to parse through each and every node to remove the "city" node. I want to remove the "city"
node in the easiest way without parsing the each node. I looked into string replace with empty but It is large data, It may fail in some cases.

Could any one tell me, what could be the better approach to remove the "city" node.

```
{
"carDetails":
[  
    {  
        "name":"John",
        "city":"Berlin",
        "cars":[  
            "audi",
            "bmw",
            "skoda": {
                "model": "f3z2",
                "manfactureDetails": {
                    "city": "vegas",
                    "time": "123967878734",
                    "color": "white",
                    "rawMaterial": {
                          "city": "london",
                          "quality": 1,
                          "importedDetails":{
                              "city" : "chile",
                              "date": "12/jan/2015",
                              ...........
                           }

                    }
                }
             }
        ],
        "job":"Teacher"
    },
    {  
        "name":"Mark",
        "city":"Oslo",
        "cars":[  
            "VW",
            "Toyata" {
               "manfactureDetails": {
                  "city" : "losangels",
                   .................
                           ..................
                }
            }

        ],
        "job":"Doctor"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [jsonia](https://github.com/robbyn/jsonia), you can remove the field "on the fly":

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("test.json")) {
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output.json");
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer)) {
            JSonHandler formatter = new JSonFormatter(out, true);
            ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            JSonHandler handler = (JSonHandler) Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl,
                    new Class<?>[] {JSonHandler.class},
                    new MyHandler(formatter));
            JSonParser.parse(stream, "UTF-8", handler);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The MyHandler class looks like this:

```
private static class MyHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private int level = 0;
    private final Object delegate;

    public MyHandler(Object delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method,
            Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (method.getName().equals("startField")
                && args[0].equals("city")) {
            ++level;
        } else if (method.getName().equals("endField")
                && args[0].equals("city")) {
            --level;
        } else if (level == 0) {
            return method.invoke(delegate, args);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Maurice Perry, the library is under LGPL license, Do we need to share our code if we use Jsonia library?

Comment: @M.S.Naidu no: with the GPL you do, but not with the LGPL.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice, this seems good but only doubt I have is with very large file. Is this ok to remove the nodes from the huge data in the file